# How can I get access to spring container?

Tags: spring

I have a spring container running, and I have class with which I want to have access to the bean created inside spring container. The class I have is not registered with the spring container.

One thing I can do is that I can use MethodInvoker to call a static method, so I will have access to static field (this would be a bean from spring container) in my class always.

Do we have class like WebapplicationContextUtils for a application that is not web?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement [`ApplicationContextAware`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html)

Comment: +1, but please provide links to newer version of the libraries.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't notice that this was old version. Here is newest: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html

Comment: I can't do this actually. Because the bean I am talking about is not registered with Spring container.
I am looking forward to using a factory class which would give me access to spring container with some static method.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you provide a static getInstance() method in your Spring-managed bean which allows objects outside of the Spring IOC container to grab an instance of that object?
Your Spring managed object most likely will be a singleton so this should work nicely.

For example:

```
public class MyObj {

  private static instance = null;

  public MyObj() {
    instance = this;
  }

  public static MyObj getInstance() {
    return instance;
  }

}

public class OutsideSpringObj {

  public doSomething() {
    MyObj springManagedObj = MyObj.getInstance();
    if (springManagedObj != null) {
      // do something with spring-managed object
    }
  }
}
```